# MYSQL: Merge two tables with different number of columns based on multiple conditions and that do not share ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
Table1:temptable3
id         |Chromosome | Start | End | Reference | Alternative | QUAL | MQ
........................................................................
NULL         chr1       12334  12335    A          TT            10   20
NULL         chr1       12334  12335    C          TT            5    3
NULL         chr2       123    123      A           T            1    2
NULL         chr2       34     34       A           T            11   60
NULL         chr3       12     12       A           T            6    NULL
```

```
Table2:TableVariants2
id          | Chromosome | Start | End | Reference | Alternative 
.............................................................
1            chr1          12334  12335   A        TT
2            chr1          12334  12335   C        TT
3            chr2          123    123     A         T
4            chr2          34     34      A         T
5            chr3          12     12      A         T
```

I want to merge them based on equal Chromosome, Start, End, Reference and Alternative and obtain:

```
id         |Chromosome | Start | End | Reference | Alternative | QUAL | MQ
........................................................................
1           chr1       12334  12335     A             TT         10     20
2           chr1       12334  12335     C             TT         5      3
3           chr2       123    123       A              T         1      2
4           chr2       34     34        A              T         11     60
5           chr3       12     12        A              T         6     NULL
```

I have tried the following but it is a never ending query...

```
UPDATE temptable3
INNER JOIN TableVariants2
ON temptable3.Chromosome = TableVariants2.Chromosome 
  AND temptable3.Start = TableVariants2.Start 
  AND temptable3.End = TableVariants2.End 
  AND temptable3.Reference = TableVariants2.Reference 
  AND temptable3.Alternative = TableVariants2.Alternative
SET temptable3.id = TableVariants2.id;
```

Comment: Which columns logically link a record in the first table with a record in the second table?

Comment: Chromosome, Start, End, Reference and Alternative must be equal between the two tables in order to link the information

Comment: Your query works fine for me https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3JEwTpb3cVL4V8g9nthgzn/0

Comment: It works fine with tables with a low number of rows but in my case I have 300,000 rows in temptable3 and 600,000 rows in TableVariants2. Then the query start but after some hours gives an error of time ("Lock wait timeout exceeded"). I would like to find a faster query, I can not afford to spend hours for the query.

Comment: @Rosa I rolled your last changes back because that changed the original question - which is not something you do - you have correctly asked a new question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables with all the columns which as a combination forms a unique id, such columns must be used in the join and select the expected columns, hope this helps.

```
    SELECT B.id, A.Chromosome,A.Start,A.End,A.Reference,A.Alternative,A.QUAL,A.MQ
    FROM temptable3 A
    INNER JOIN TableVariants2 B
    ON A.CHROMOSOME=B.CHROMOSOME AND A.START=B.STAR AND A.END=B.END
    AND A.REFERENCE=B.REFERENCE AND A.ALTERNATE=B.ALTERNATE
```

Comment: This answer would produce the desired result.

Comment: @Drummad No, it won't, q.v. Strawberry's comment above.  `SELECT *` would include the join columns twice.

Comment: The answer is specifically selecting the required columns, hence my comment.

Comment: Yes it was, and I agree that it was wrong before the edit but it was edited before I posted my comment. Hence my comment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Ajan ! That works however is still too slow for big tables. I think that the problem is the INNER JOIN but I am not sure if there are a faster solution.